# When and how do I use a Smith chart?

Tags: feed-line, impedance

What are some real-world problems that a Smith chart can help me solve? Ultimately I'd like to gain a more intuitive understanding of the space the chart represents, but it seems to me that actual, repeated use -- or reviewing concrete, detailed examples -- are the best way to get there.

Comment: This may be too broad of a question, as there are lots of Smith chart usages. Perhaps you could come up with a specific use case.

Comment: Perhaps you could also suggest a tag-wiki entry, as I had to Google what a Smith Chart was!